# Creating CheckBoxList in Visual Studio 2015 ----> Sql Server 2014

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server

I've searched around for days and I've found many posts/answers to this question but it doesn't pertain to my exact situation or I just can't figure it out.

Essentially, I need to insert a CheckBoxList into a Visual Basic ASP.NET Web page that I have designed that includes, let's say, 5 choices for the user to choose from. We'll call this Choice 1 through Choice 5 for simplicity.

I've created the CheckBoxList in the Web Page that contains choice 1-5 as options, now how exactly do I tie those choices to the corresponding table in Sql? I have the connection established with the Tables I need created in the Database. I could have the Table for this checkboxlist setup wrong, that's why I'm on here.

Under Column Name, I have Choice 1 - 5 and their corresponding data types.

Any insight would be amazing as I've been stuck here for a few days scratching my head.

Here's a rough idea of what I have:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "tie [them[ to the corresponding table in Sql"? Are you trying to get the names of the choices from SQL? Or is some action supposed to be saved to a table when the web form is submitted?

Comment: I guess the right word would've been "bind". I was wanting, when the user goes to the web form, and selects a choice(s), for those selected choices to update in the sql database as a  bit, on or off.

Comment: You have found many answers but none then fits your situation. Such a rare situation you have. Can you share the rare code which you have tried to solve your issue but didn't work for you? Did you actually try using any of the solutions you found online?

Comment: I have tried several of them. Basically, all the answers I have found pertain to creating the CheckBoxList in the webform, creating a data connection to the database/specific table, and pulling the names from the table and inserting those into the CheckBoxList. It's hard for me to explain. So I'll post exactly what I've been trying to follow. https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Insert-multiple-values-from-CheckBoxList-to-Database-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: Your question is not well formed and does not explain your specific problem. While you discuss your checkbox, UI element, you seem to be questioning your data structure rather than the functioning of the Checkbox.  Rephrase your question so that it specifically describes the issue as a Business State (data) issue or a User Interface (Checkbox) Issue.  They are completely separate issues.

Comment: I'm questioning the functioning of the CheckBoxList > My structure. The only time I question my structure is in one sentence, that there should show that I'm having more trouble actually binding the data of the CheckBoxList to the Sql table or vice versa. Whichever way is easiest or makes the most sense in my case. I don't really know how else to explain it.

Comment: Are you a Native English speaker?? You still have not clarified the issue.  Taking what you have presented though, it seems that your checkbox returns the selection(s) as a form post. In asp.net you do not have a "binding' between a UI element and a data model on the server side. When the form posts back you have to extract the desired form data and update the data store with the changes.

Comment: Yes.. born and raised in the United States, but what does that have to do with my issue?

Comment: As I said earlier, you are not providing a well formed question. Is it that you are having trouble updating the data store, are you having trouble getting the data from the postback form or are you not sure exactly how your data store should be structured. All three are implied in your original post.

Comment: Show your postback code that updates the data store(database)

Comment: I have yet to get that far. But I just figured out how to get the CheckBoxList to pull it's Options (the actual checkboxes) from my Sql DB. I'm moving on to getting the selected options to update in the DB currently.

Comment: Good Luck in your endeavors...:)